# Parcelable transfer fails

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I'm trying my first Parcelable transfer and it doesn't go fine. This is my Parcelable class :

```
public class Element implements Parcelable, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String name;
    String id;
    byte[] password;

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Element> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Element>() {

        public Element createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Element(source);
        }

        public Element[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Element[size];
        }

    };

    private Element(Parcel in){
        name = in.readString();
        id = in.readString();
        password = new byte[in.readInt()];
        in.readByteArray(password);
    }
    public Element(String name,String id,byte[] password){
        this.name=name;
        this.id=id;
        this.password=password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(id);
        dest.writeInt(password.length);
        dest.writeByteArray(password);
    }

}
```

As you see, it's a simple Parcelable with 2 String fields and 1 byteArray.

Now I send it to the second activity via my main one :

```
            //Inside the main activity
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("element", (Parcelable)adapter.getItem(pos));
            startActivity(i);
```

And then, I receive the Parcelable in the second activity :

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);

        Element e = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("element");
        //this line makes my app crash. No idea why.
```

Comment: Could you post the exception?

Comment: I don't know how to get it. I'm using AIDE IDE and the Logcat shows nothing...

Comment: There is no reason to implement `Serializable` and `Parcelable`. You should implement one or the other. This may or may not have anything to so with your problem.

Comment: Also, if your app is crashing there is definitely an exception and stack trace in the logcat. If you aren't seeing it, you are probably filtering the logcat and missing it. Make sure that you are NOT filtering the logcat when debugging. You will miss all kinds of important/relevant stuff.

Comment: Also, don't cast your `Element` to `Parcelable` when calling `putExtra()`.

Comment: I think you're right. Even if I don't realy understand why it's a problem... Anyway, I just replaced the putExtra(element) by putting each data (the 2 String and the byteArray) and it worked.
About the logcat, I think it's just the logcat of AIDE which is a shit. I'll try to find an external one.
Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: I have to cast to Parcelable because putExtra(String, Parcelable) and putExtra(String, Serializable) both exist. putExtra(string, element) is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
Element obj = new Element();

//set your data here before send

Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
i.putExtra("com.package.Element", obj);

startActivity(i);
```

Then to retrieve it:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        Element obj = b.getParcelable("com.package.Element");
    }

}
```

Comment: It didn't work neither. Ok I will try to pass everything directly, without the Parcelable.

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with the same issue. In your manifest in the MyActivity activity add:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

It solved the issue for me.

```
<activity android:name="com.example.myapp.MyActivity"
android:label="@string/title_myactivity"
android:launchMode="singleTop">
</activity>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why would you implement both Parcelable and Serializable?